# How to get the nodes within an animation in AnimationPlayer?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm trying to get all the nodes which are effected by an animation

[image]

I know that it's possible to find them through looping tracks:

```
for track_indx in animation.get_track_count():
        var track_node=get_node(animation.track_get_path(track_indx));
        if(!list.has(track_node))
            list.append(track_node);
```

but it seems unnecessary iterating over all the tracks just to get the nodes, especially when there are too many tracks attached to just one node.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**There isn't a better way.**

---

I just want to remind you that the paths of tracks are relative to the `root_node` of the `AnimationPlayer`. You can deal with relative `NodePath`s by getting the node they are relative to, and using `get_node` from it:

```
var animation_player := get_node("AnAnimationPlayer") as AnimationPlayer
var animation := animation_player.get_animation("AnAnimation")
var root_node := animation_player.get_node(animation_player.root_node)

var list := []

for track_indx in animation.get_track_count():
    var track_node := root_node.get_node(animation.track_get_path(track_indx))
    if not list.has(track_node):
        list.append(track_node)

for item in list:
    print(item)
```